# limiting date histogram to a date range without affecting results

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to limit the results to a date range while performing the date histogram. But it seems to affect the results set (hits). Is there any way that I can do the same, but not affect the hits area?

Comment: Can you update your question with the current query you have and some sample results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) would be an ideal match here.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Content": "my query"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "filterByDate": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "<dateField>": {
            "gte": "<StartDate>",
            "lt": "<EndDate>"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "dateStats": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "<dateField>"
              }
            }
          }
        }  
      }
    }
```